# Right-Alt modifier no longer works in most programs

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, special-characters, visual-studio-2017

I'm a programmer. You can guess I use the { } and [ ] characters a lot.

I am on a French Canadian Keyboard, and I of course checked that this is till the case in the context of my issue. On this keyboard, I can type those characters using the right alt key plus some keys on my right hand side.[image]

Today, out of nowhere when I started using the computer, this did not work anymore. **all the other characters, including capital letters, accents and special characters, are in their expected locations**, except for those that required the right alt to be held. Specifically, they behaves as if I was not touching that alt key, so the characters are simply not available.

I have checked and double checked, I am still on the same keyboard configuration, and those characters are not available with another key combination, they are simply not accessible because the alt key does not get recognized.

Except for Visual Studio.

In Visual Studio, everything behaves as it did before. I can get those characters easily by pressing the normal combination.

But in every other program (Notepad, Notepad++, Paint, Google Chrome, etc), the alt key doesn't seem to get recognized. I literally had to copy-paste the chars into this question and in the above picture from Visual Studio.

I have Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.8.7 if that makes any difference.

I am using Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Version 1809 64 bits. My keyboard is pretty much standard, nothing special or fancy about it.

Comment: Have you installed any key-mapping software (such as AutoHotKey)?

Comment: The only thing I installed recently is TeamViewer. Can that be the cause?

Comment: Unlikely, but can be checked by uninstalling it.

Comment: You possibly have pressed left ALT + left SHIFT or left CTRL + left SHIFT, these 2 keyboard combinations change the keyboard layout and language.

Comment: @LPChip I specifically mentioned I double checked the keyboard layouts. It is the same in Visual Studio as in the other programs, and it is the correct one.

Comment: You would not have been the first who stated they checked the keyboard layout, only to find out that the language changed or visa versa. In IT there's nothing so complicated as someone stating they checked something, only to find out when you check it, that it is different. So I learned the hard way over and over again, to always double check. Also because these settings are changable per program and will change the moment you switch to a different program.